# Android ListItem with radio button

Tags: android

My page has a listView and a OK button.  Each listItem has an id and RadioButtonGroup.
I am using SimpleCursorAdapter to load the list.

What I would like to do is when I click on OK, I want to get individual id and radio button selection from that radioButtonGroup.

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a clicklistener to your list:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    RadioButton button = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.RadioButton);
    button.getId();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to extend the SimpleCursorAdapter class and inside the newView / bindView methods you need to check for the state of the radioButtonGroup. In order to do that you need to set a listener for your radio button group using the [OnCheckedChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener%29). I have some source code example that I used on a personal app. Bare in mind that I'm listening to checkboxes but is should be perfectly straight forward to adapt to a radio button group.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    NoteHolder holder = (NoteHolder) view.getTag();

    holder.titleView.setText(cursor.getString(titleColIndex));
    holder.modifiedView.setText(mUtils.formatDate(mUtils.formatDateFromString (cursor.getString(modifiedColIndex), context, "dd-MM-yyyy"), "dd-MM-yyyy"));
    holder.priorityView.setImageResource(mUtils.getPriorityResourceId(cursor.getInt(priorityColIndex)));

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/ARLRDBD.TTF");
    holder.titleView.setTypeface(tf);
    holder.modifiedView.setTypeface(tf);

    final int pos = cursor.getPosition();
    final long id = cursor.getLong(idColIndex);

    holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkChecked(v, pos, id);
        }
    });

    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rowCheckChecked(v, pos, id);
        }
    });

    holder.checkbox.setChecked(itemChecked.get(pos));
}

private static class NoteHolder {
    TextView titleView;
    TextView modifiedView;
    ImageView priorityView;
    CheckBox checkbox;
}

private void checkChecked(View v, int pos, long id){

    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.delete_checkbox);
    if (cb.isChecked())
    {
        itemChecked.set(pos, true);
        mSelectedIDs.add(id);
    }
    else if(!cb.isChecked())
    {
        itemChecked.set(pos, false);
        if(mSelectedIDs.contains(id))
            mSelectedIDs.remove(id);
    }
}
```

I would advise you to use a viewHolder pattern too. Specially if your app is going to have many list items. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern) and see an example [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List14.html), you can also see it implemented in the code I've put above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am reading about ViewHolder and trying the solution u provided. Now I have another question how do I call getView on click of a button?

Comment: You don't call getView, and for this example you don't use getView, you use newView, bindView, basicly it's getView but it's already separated for a newView or a recycled View. bindView is always called, newView is only called when it's new. Check this link it will help you too: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296