# Android Photo stream layout like instagram

Tags: android, android-layout, instagram

I need to create a photo feed layout for android similar to instagram's. What is the best layout to use as the parent? A TableView or a ListView? Something else? Also how does Instagram not run out of memory loading so many photos at once?

Comment: TO answer your second question, I would assume compression and disposing and loading in images as sectors rather than everything at once. I don't know anything about instigram. However, you question is a little bit to vague and isn't specific enough for StackOverFlow. I might be proven wrong though.

Comment: Well my only guess as to the memory is that one of these layout types handles "recycling" of its "cells" on its own? I think I remember reading something like that but I'm unsure if that is the case with custom "Cells"

Comment: If you want to see what views an application uses, you can use [HierarchyViewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html) to examine it.

Comment: that looks like it will be a pretty good jumping off point for me I suppose

Comment: @mpatten It could be that a lot of these interface things attempt to do this internally. Recycling cells is the same as pooling and it may or may not be beneficial; recycling complex objects can yield some unexpected behavior. Displaying things on a screen is very similar to how videogames do this; if its not on the screen don't draw it. An easy way to get anything out of memory is to temporary cache it onto a storage medium and then load it back into memory when necessary. Storage these days is fairly quick that you can get away with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) does what you are looking for, and is fed by a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).  This will also handle recycling views to manage memory.

Comment: Using the GridView would I need to define a Row class to inflate and fill with data to add to the gridView?

Comment: Yes, you would inflate your grid cells the same way you inflate rows in a ListView. Override [getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) and inflate your cell layout.  Don't forget to use the [view holder pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern) for smooth performance.