# ListView Viewholder checkbox state

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I've some problems with my ListView custom adapter (and its newly implemented viewHolder). I have a ListView with a checkbox for each item (nothing new here). The problem is, if there is more than 9 items in my list, when I check the first checkbox, the tenth will be automatically checked (same for the second with the eleventh) just like if there were one listener for both item (and I beleive it's the case in some way).

I read about the position issue with listView, view recycling and the ViewHolder way to solve it here: [How can I make my ArrayAdapter follow the ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern)

But I probably made something wrong because it's not working...

```
public class PresenceListAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {
private LayoutInflater  inflater;
private List<Integer> ids;
private List<String> statuts;

public PresenceListAdapter (Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to, List<Integer> ids, List<String> statuts)
{
    super (context, data, resource, from, to);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from (context);
    this.ids = ids;
    this.statuts= statuts;

}

@Override
public Object getItem (int position)
{
    return super.getItem (position);
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{

    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate (R.layout.list_text_checkbox, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnRetard);
        holder.check = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkPresent);

        if (statuts.get(position).equals("P")) {
            Drawable img = inflater.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_online);
            holder.btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
            holder.btn.setEnabled(true);
            holder.check.setChecked(true);
        }
        else if(statuts.get(position).equals("R"))
        {
            Drawable img = inflater.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_away);
            holder.btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
            holder.btn.setEnabled(true);
            holder.check.setChecked(true);
        }
        else 
        {
            Drawable img = inflater.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.presence_invisible);
            holder.btn.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
            holder.check.setChecked(false);
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else 
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    int id = ids.get(position);

    if(id != 0)
    {
        holder.check.setTag(id);
        holder.btn.setTag(id);
    }

    return super.getView (position, convertView, parent);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    Button btn;
    CheckBox check;
}
```

And my listener:
        public void changerPresent(View v) {

```
    CheckBox checkPresent = (CheckBox) v;
    int idPersonne = (Integer) checkPresent.getTag();
    View parent = (View)v.getParent();
    Button btn = (Button) parent.findViewById(R.id.btnRetard);

    if(checkPresent.isChecked()) {
        gestion.updatePresence(idPersonne, idSeance, "P");

        btn.setEnabled(true);
        setBtnRetardPresent(btn);           
    }
    else 
    {
        gestion.updatePresence(idPersonne, idSeance, "A");
        btn.setEnabled(false);
        setBtnRetardAbsent(btn);

    }

}
```

I would appreciate any help at this point, I'm working on this for hours now.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's how I made it work:

First, you need a separate array for your checked state. It has to be the same size as your adapter's `getCount()`.

Then on your getView, your checkbox's setOnCheckedChangedListener MUST PRECEED your checkbox.setChecked statements.

example:

```
holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    isChecked[position] = isChecked;
  }
});

holder.checkBox.setChecked(isChecked[position]);
```

Comment: Interesting, Can you please tell why checkchangelistener must precede setChecked ? Thanks

Comment: if you have other things you want to do in the onCheckChanged (such as update the list item color, etc), these things will not happen if you call setChecked before setting the listener.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, setCheckChanged is called in getView method whenever it is recycled (getView mechanism). Not expected way.

Comment: I could not see your comment, Yes those updation is not happening in list item. Question is why ?

Comment: Because simple logic in the order of execution. If you call setChecked before setting the listener, the onCheckChanged will not be triggered. (1 +1) / 2 does not have the same result as (1 / 2) + 1.

Comment: Answers like these on SO, turn life easy :)

Comment: wtf? How can this have an effect when the click-listener is triggered waaaaaay later?

Comment: @avalancha because you're already triggering it when you call `setChecked`

Comment: Or you could set onCheckChanged listener to null before you use setChecked. Using setChecked triggers the event, too.

Comment: @InsignificantPerson That would work if it's only the checkbox you want to update. However if you're doing something else (like setting some TextView to bold when the checkbox is checked, for example), this is the easiest way to do it.

Comment: doesn't work for me, selects the checkboxes as soon as new views are generated ! Any new tips you might have tried on for this problem !

Comment: When I rotate the screen, all selected checkboxes are unselected. It restarts the list view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of the fact that listview recycles it views

so in `getView(`) method

```
     if (convertView == null)
        {
    ........
         }
    else 
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        }
  // Uncheck needed boxes here... You need to implement your logic 
        if( 'position' is checked earlier)
         holder.check.setChecked(true);
        else
        holder.check.setChecked(false);
```

You need to write the code to manage the state of view if the convert is not null, because it is a already used view which may be having checked check boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You should set CheckedBox state outside the initialization of ViewHolder, like the following code:

```
if (convertView == null) {
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

viewHolder.checkedBox.setChecked();
```

BTW: use SparseBooleanArray instead of two list to store CheckedBox state.