# How do I make a Multiple checkbox stay in the same state every time I open my app?

Tags: android

This is my adapter class
I have to check the checkbox click again when open app again,my data is correctly saved in preference and it is compared well too but problem is it does not show checked on checkbox inside for loop, any help will be appriciated

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //getting sharedpreference DATa here
    animals = PoJo.readList(context, "savingkeyforcheckbox");
    final RecordHolder holder;
    view = convertView;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.items, parent, false);
        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        holder.packagename = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.packagename);
        holder.clickpackage_checkbox = (CheckBox) view
                .findViewById(R.id.clickpackage_checkbox);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (RecordHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setId(position);
    holder.packagename.setId(position);
    item = getItem(position);
    if (animals.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < animals.size(); i++) {
            if (animals.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase(item.getLabel())) {
                Log.e("do check here", "CHECK");
                holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(true);
            } else {
                holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(false);

            }
        }
    } else {
        holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }
    if (booleanArray.get(position)) {
        holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(true);
        item.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(false);
        item.setChecked(false);
    }

    holder.packagename.setText(item.getLabel());
    Drawable icons = Utilities.createIconThumbnail(item.getIcon(), context);
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(icons);
    holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.clickpackage_checkbox.isChecked()) {
                booleanArray.put(position, true);
            selecteditems.add(listofitems.get(position).getLabel());
            } else {
                booleanArray.put(position, false);
                selecteditems.remove(listofitems.get(position).getLabel());
            }
        }
    });
    //POJO IS MODEL CLASS AND SAVING PREFERENCES OF ITEMS IN WRITELIST
    PoJo.writeList(context, selecteditems, "savingkeyforcheckbox");
    SelectedAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: you can use shared preference to save state and while opening your app retrieve the state and set them to your checkboxes.

Comment: does it enter the if condition? I mean does it print out "do check here: CHECK"?

Comment: Have you tried putting `Log.e("do check here", "UNCHECK")` in the else condition after that?

`else {
Log.e("do check here", "UNCHECK");
holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(false);
}`

Comment: @denis_lor ya denis i did but while adding this it uncheck all my checkbox

Comment: I know that error came because of using  this below code it recreate view but i dont know how to resolve this pls help booleanarray is SparseBooleanArray if (booleanArray.get(position)) {
        holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.clickpackage_checkbox.setChecked(false);
    }

Comment: @SunilChaudhary try this solution as stated in the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350670/listview-viewholder-checkbox-state

Answer (score 0):

You can use Getter and Setter for save and retrieve checkbox value from preference
 and set that to checkbox.