# checkbox's in a listView / adapter are "pressed" on their own

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, adapter

UPDATE #2
i have a listView and an adapter. each item in the listView has a checkbox.
when clicking on a checkbox in the list view, the checkboxs 5-6 items below (repetitive - all checkboxs ) are also seemed as pressed - the light is on, even tho no one click on then, and when checking if its actually pressed with 'isChecked' bool flag, it is false.

public class watchAllAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
public watchAllAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Subject> arrayList) {
    super(context, 0, arrayList);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.for_each_watch_all, parent, false);
    }
    final Subject currSubject = getItem(position);

    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_for_each);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                currSubject.setChosen(true);
            }
            else{
                cb.setChecked(false);
                currSubject.setChosen(false);
            }
        }
    });

    return listItemView;
}
```

thanks =]

Comment: please post your code below so that we can check it

Comment: did it, thanks for responding , new to this =].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow View Holder pattern. Create one Holder class and reuse the view if it's not null. Also set onCheckedChangedListener() for check box to null if view is already there.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.for_each_watch_all, parent, false);
        holder = new Holder();

        holder.ckbox =(CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.check_box_id);

        listItemView .setTag(holder);
    }else {

        holder = (Holder) listItemView.getTag();
        holder.ckbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);

    }
    final Subject currSubject = getItem(position);

    final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_for_each);
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                currSubject.setChosen(true);
            }
            else{
                cb.setChecked(false);
                currSubject.setChosen(false);
            }
        }
    });

    return listItemView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    CheckBox checkBox;
}
```

Comment: in line 9 of your sol, who is 'row'? i can access the R.id.... with listItemView... tho its null in this 'if'..., EDIT: and who is "R.id.check_box_id"?

Comment: Replace it with listItemView

Comment: did that, the same problem remains.

Comment: problem solved using your solutoion and 'josephus' from here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350670/listview-viewholder-checkbox-state, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would suggest just using...

```
if(cb.isChecked()) {
    currSubject.setChosen(true);
}
else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
    currSubject.setChosen(false);
}
```

Comment: And how check box `checked` or `unchecked` cases will be handled??