# When is a ListFragment view fully inflated? Problems with contextual action bar

Tags: android, checkbox

I am writing a new Android activity and am having trouble with a `ListFragment`. The idea here is that the parent activity hosts a `ListFragment` whose data is pulled from the database using an adapter. When the contextual action bar (CAB) is invoked, a `CheckBox` item (which is part of the layout for each row in the `ListView` hosted by the `ListFragment`) becomes visible. The `CheckBox` items are not visible by default. The `CheckBox` items are checked inside my `MultiChoiceModeListener` classes `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` method.

My goal is to preserve the state of the checkboxes when the screen orientation changes.

When the orientation changes with the CAB activated, the CheckBox items in each row of the ListView (hosted by ListFragment) become invisible. I presume this is because the `ListFragment` is redrawn via the `onCreateView()` callback.

However, my problem is that when trying to re-enable the checkboxes I am getting a NULL pointer exception. When is it appropriate to access the row view elements from the fragment? If I wait very long (i.e, re-enable inside `onItemCheckedStateChanged()`, which is not ideal because I dont want to have to re-click everything!), the checkbox can be accessed and set visible. If I try to access this from the fragment earlier (for example in `onCreateView()` or `onViewCreated()`) the checkbox item is NULL but the rest of the row view is not null.

Any suggestions? Here is some code:

**The Null Pointer Exception is being being thrown inside `restoreSelectedCheckBoxes()`. The lines are identified below.**

**From parent `Activity`**

```
// In the parent activity. Called from onCreate()
private void displayListViewTEMP() {
    // add fragment to apropriate layout item, but do not overwrite!
    FragmentTransaction fTrans;
    FragmentManager fMan = getFragmentManager();

    // fragContainer is null until something is added to it
    if (fMan.findFragmentByTag(Activity_Home.NAME_LIST_FRAG_TAG) == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Adding fragment to feed_list_container");
        fTrans = fMan.beginTransaction();
        fTrans.add(R.id.feed_list_container, new Name_List(), Activity_Home.NAME_LIST_FRAG_TAG);
        fTrans.commit();
    }
}
```

**From `ListFragment`**

```
// this is the method I call to restore the checkboxes
public void restoreSelectedCheckBoxes() {

    Log.i(TAG, "restoring selected button state");
    ListView v = getListView();
    // this variable holds the indices of selected items in the list
    int selCnt = selectedListItems.size();
    CheckBox bx;

    for (int i = 0; i < selCnt; i++) {
        Log.i(TAG, "v = " + v);             <-- prints valid oref
        bx = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);
        Log.i(TAG, "bx = " + bx);           <-- prints 'null' after orientation change
        bx.setChecked(true);                <-- NULL pointer exception
    }

}
```

And here is the data I use to set up the CAB:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // omitted code to set up adapter

    ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(getChoiceListener());
}

// set up contextual action bar
private MultiChoiceModeListener getChoiceListener() {
    if (this.choiceListener != null)
        return this.choiceListener;

    this.choiceListener = new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        @Override
        // Inflate the menu for the CAB
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

            Log.i(TAG, "Creating contextual action bar");
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_name_context, menu);

            ListView v = getListView();
            int vCnt = v.getCount();
            View child;
            CheckBox bx; 

            // set checkbox subviews as visible
            for (int i = 0; i < vCnt; i++) {
                child = v.getChildAt(i);
                if (child == null)
                    continue;
                bx = (CheckBox) child.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);
                bx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }
        // omitted other overridden methods that aren't relevant        
    };
    return this.choiceListener;
}
```

**Thank you so much for the help! The solution was indeed to override the adapter as suggested. See the final code: **

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if (selectedListItems.contains(position)) {
        CheckBox bx = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);
        bx.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        bx.setChecked(true);
    }
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Could you say exactly which line is giving you the NPE?

Comment: I've added that detail. See restoreSelectedCheckBoxes() in the code

Comment: The problem is here: `bx = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.item_checkbox);` because v is a ListView, but the checkboxes are in views used to populate the listview. Use mikejonesguy's suggestion of modifying the adapter, because that is what handles the View of each row in the ListView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of adapter are you using for your ListFragment?

I would create an adapter class by extending ArrayAdapter (or whatever you're using now) and add the state restoration logic to the adapter.getView() method rather than trying to muck with waiting until your views are done with layout, etc.

See this post if you aren't sure how to extend the ArrayAdapter: [How can I make my ArrayAdapter follow the ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern)

Comment: Thank you so much! This did it. I overrode the getView() method. Solution at the bottom of my question

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
getView().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code you want to run when view is visible/inflated for the first time
    }
 }
);
```

Comment: Thank you Vee. Could you please explain how this helps this particular issue, as well as which view this should be associated with? The fragment or the list row?

Comment: This should be associated with the fragment.

What this does is ensures that your code will not run until the view is fully rendered.

Comment: Hmm, I wrapped the code inside restoreSelectedCheckBoxes() in a runnable like suggested, but it didnt change the behavior at all. Where would you have added this? To be clear, the view renders properly during the first load.

Comment: You can't post on getView() if it's null. You could post on a new handler instead, but that isn't the root issue.