# Android ListView Sourced from REST JSON response

Tags: android, json, rest, listview

I can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for after a few day's worth of hunting, so if anyone has seen exactly what I'm trying to do elsewhere, I'd love a link or two.

Anyway, I'm trying to build an app to connect into an ERP system that returns user access information in JSON format via REST request using an e-mail address and password. Most users of the system only have a singular access role, so no big deal for them, but others have multiple roles. The trouble I'm having is taking these multiple access roles and adding them into a ListView where they can select the role with which they wish to use to gain access.

Trouble is, I need a display that uses two lines per selection (to properly display all user-pertinent data) and some way to record the user selection. The data useful in the background for the selection would not be displayed, as it would not mean anything to the user. I've been able to take the JSON response and map it to a custom class I designed for it without any problems (not actually all that useful, mostly only helps for discerning the results count prior to displaying multiple results to the ListView). But I can't figure out how to properly build the ListView layout and map the data to the layout. I'm having trouble understanding how to build the view and insert data into new list items.

The best I figure, if I can get the results to display in a ListView and then record the selection in the shared preferences, I'll be golden.

Comment: 2 links for u to help make sense of things ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern     https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: This looks to be right up the alley of what I was looking for. I'll give this a shot and see how well I can make it work. Thank you.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I guess I was using the wrong search criteria to find all of this, but now I have this working nicely. Now if only I could get the ListView selection to work.

Answer (score 0):

If the listview items being populated from some JSONArray then you could use `listview.setOnItemClickListener` to get the position of the selected item and match it from the array.Your question seems a little vague. Can you post some code of what you've tried so that it becomes a little clearer?

Comment: I would be more than glad to if I hadn't deleted it all. It was nothing more than a confusing mess of spaghetti and comments, a testament to confusion and failure.