# Using 'this' in an Android event handler. Is there a better way?

Tags: android, listview

Yes, there is always a better way.  But is there a better way that is possible? :)

So this code works.  It's a custom adapter for a ListActivty and the idea is that each row has a button and when the button is tapped the item for that row is removed and the list refreshes.

```
private class ThirdActivityAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context ctx;
    private List<String> items;
    public ThirdActivityAdapter(Context ctx, List<String> items) {
        super(ctx, R.layout.third_activity_list_row, items);
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<String> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_activity_list_row, parent, false);
        TextView txt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.third_activity_list_row_text);
        Button btn  = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.third_activity_list_row_btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                View view = (View)v.getParent();
                ListView listView = (ListView)view.getParent();
                ThirdActivityAdapter.this.items.remove(listView.getPositionForView(view));
                ThirdActivityAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        txt.setText(items.get(position));
        return row;
    }
```

In the click listener, I am using `ThirdActivityAdapter.this` to get at the items in the adapter.  Is there a better way to do this?  I can see how an external source would work but I wanted to see if there was a better design before I continue.

Thanks!

Comment: *"Yes, there is always a better way. But is there a better way that is possible?"*. If there was a better way but it wasn't possible, then it wouldn't really be a better way. It would be...not a way

Comment: You don't need to use `ThirdActivityAdapter.this` with items.remove or with notifyDataSetChanged. you can do it directly too.

Comment: That's the better way.  For some reason I thought that `items` would not be accessible because it wasn't final.

Comment: dont create a new listener object each time getView() is called, just let your ThirdActivityAdapter implement OnClickListener and that way you will have only one listener

Answer (score 0):

There *is* a better way, if I understand your question correctly. It involves using the View.setTag(key, value). It lets you assign a key-value pair to a particular view, and access it later using View.getTag(key).

Here's what I would do:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_activity_list_row, parent, false);
    TextView txt = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.third_activity_list_row_text);
    Button btn  = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.third_activity_list_row_btn);
    btn.setTag(R.id.button_position, position); // Save position to View
    btn.setOnClickListener(mYourClickListener);
    txt.setText(items.get(position));
    return row;
}
View.OnClickListener mYourClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = v.getTag(R.id.view_position); // Obtain position
        removeItem(position);
    }
}
// Avoids this syntax because its clear to whom this method belongs.
private void remoteItem(int position) {
    items.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Also, look into using the [ViewHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern) pattern to avoid repeated references to `findViewById()`.

Comment: That's close.  I can't try it right now.  I think that will work.  But in the click listener would need to get the parent of the button and then tag because the view sent to onClick is the button and I need the row because that's where the tag is attached.  I guess could also set the tag on the button itself.