# Custom ListView ArrayAdapter not displaying filtered data

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am displaying some data in ListView using my custom ArrayAdapter class. I have a spinner in Action Bar and based on it's item selection I want to filter the data and repopulate it in the list view.

Currently when my activity loads the data shows up correctly, but when I select any item from the spinner, the ListView gets empty and does not show any data, although the Actionbar still appears.

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is my custom ArrayAdapter Class :

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

private ArrayList < ArrayList < String >> arrayList;    
private LayoutInflater theInflater;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList arrayList) {
    super(context, R.layout.row_layout, arrayList);
    this.arrayList = arrayList;

}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    theInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

    View theView = theInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);

    ArrayList < String > values = (ArrayList < String > ) getItem(position);

    TextView a= (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.a);
    TextView b= (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.b);
    TextView c= (TextView) theView.findViewById(R.id.c);

    a.setText(values.get(0));
    b.setText(values.get(1));
    c.setText(values.get(2));

    return theView;
}


public Filter geFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {@Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
            al.add("ValueA1");
            al.add("ValueA2");
            al.add("ValueA3");

            ArrayList bl = new ArrayList();
            bl.add("ValueB1");
            bl.add("ValueB2");
            bl.add("ValueB3");

            ArrayList < ArrayList < String >> array = new ArrayList < > ();

            array.add(al);
            array.add(bl);

            results.count = array.size();
            results.values = array;

            return results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {


            arrayList = (ArrayList) results.values;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    return filter;
 }

}
```

In Spinner's item selected listener, I have :

```
theAdapter.getFilter().filter("Incoming");
```

Comment: You have to pass spinner selected position , filter result will be empty for Incoming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's a lot you are doing wrong with the adapter. Such as not implementing the [ViewHolder paradigm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3832467/1243753). Note, this is not why you are seeing issues. However it does solve performance issues your solution will create.

The filtering itself is not working because `ArrayAdapter` tracks it's own internal list of data. The `ArrayAdapter` makes no guarantees that the list you are tracking externally is the same one. This is especially true during a filter operation. You can read more about the dangers of tracking an external list like you are [here](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/constructor-woes-androids-arrayadapter/).

Your `Filter` is very problematic.

1. It re-assigns your external list of data to a new list, which means your `arrayList` is no longer the same one the internal `ArrayAdapter` is tracking. This will cause issues later on when you mutate the adapter.
2. As it stands, your implementation doesn't seem to actually filter anything. Usually you'll also have a second `ArrayList` in order to track the original data before the filtering starts.  Otherwise there's no way to restore the data that was filtered out.
3. `performFiltering()` takes place on a background thread.  While you don't seem to access `arrayList` during this method (which would be the only way to actually filter the data), you need to ensure all list modifications are synchronized.  `ArrayAdapter` itself already handles synchronization but there's no way to sync your external `arrayList` with it. Meaning you can't actually write a filter without risking concurrent modification errors.
4. In `publishResults()` when `results.count == 0`, you must `notifyDataSetInvalidated()`.  If `results.count > 0`, you must `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
5. `ArrayAdapter` already implements `Filterable`. It's redundant to add that to your custom adapter.

There are a few bugs with the `ArrayAdapter` own filterable implementation. Here's [a piece](http://www.jaysoyer.com/2014/07/filtering-problems-arrayadapter/) which talks about the problem and how to work around it. The relevance is that it discusses how to create your own filterable logic to fix the problem. The short, you can't create your own custom filter with the `ArrayAdapter`.  You need to create your own adapter from scratch using `BaseAdapter` instead.

Alternatively, you can use a [third party library](https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters) which provides a very easy means to implement your own custom filtering logic. I highly suggest taking a look at that guy instead.  Additionaly, I highly recommend you Google around more on how to properly create a custom adapter. There's a lot to them and a lot you'll need to learn to properly implement one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following in `publishResults()` method:

Clear the list, add the resultant data again and call `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` again.

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

     arrayList = (ArrayList) results.values;
     notifyDataSetChanged();

     clear();
     for(int i = 0, l = arrayList.size(); i < l; i++) {
            add(arrayList.get(i));
     }
     notifyDataSetInvalidated(); 
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please tell where should I use this piece of code ?

Comment: I just tried the above code but the result is the same. Not displaying any data on spinner item select event.