# Getting checked items with custom adapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I have listview with custom adapter. Every element of this listview has checkbox. Standart function .getCheckedItemPositions() does not work.

onCreate:

```
  final String[] words = new String[] {
                "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
        };


        MySimpleArrayAdapter adapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(this, words);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

My adapter:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;
    private final String[] values;
    DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    int id = 1;


    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
        super(context, R.layout.listitem, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        TextView newwordview = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.newwordview);


        newwordview.setText("lalala");

            return rowView;
    }
}
```

Here i try to get checked items:

```
public void addbtnclick(View view){
        int cntChoice = listView.getCount();
        SparseBooleanArray sparseBooleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

        for (int i = 0; i < cntChoice; i++) {

            if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == true) {
                String a = listView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                myDbHelper.setadd(a, "en");
            } else if (sparseBooleanArray.get(i) == false) {

            }
        }
    }
```

In debug sparseBooleanArray always has 0 items.
What should I do?

Comment: What's the issue/error you are receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably make your `Adapter` a list of objects that can retain their checked state, rather than strings.

```
public class Item
{
    public String title;
    public boolean checked;
}
```

Then:

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>
{
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        TextView newwordview = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.newwordview);

        Item item = getItem(position);
        newwordview.setText(item.title);
        checkBox.setChecked(item.checked);


        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked)
            {
                Item item = getItem(position);
                item.checked = isChecked;
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

ALSO: You should really be re-using the convertView when present for performance reasons. I recommend looking at the view holder pattern: 
[How can I make my ArrayAdapter follow the ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern)

Comment: Variable 'position' is accessed within inner class; needs to be declared final

Comment: Did you notice and include the `final` keyword in the method signature above? `getView(final int position, `...

Comment: In onCheckedChanged I had to add **setItemChecked** : `myListView.setItemChecked(position, isChecked);` to get getCheckedItemPositions() works. myListView is initialized in the constructor with 
    `public customAdapter(Context context,List<myObject> cat,ListView mListView) {
..}`