# Android Studio (Referencing Objects)

Tags: java, android, debugging, reference

A former VB6 programmer starting out with Android Studio.

I'm trying to reference an ItemList on my layout. In VB I'd do something like Me.ItemList or ThisForm.ItemList

But I know that MyActivity.XML.ItemList just won't do it. How can I properly reference the ItemList control?

Sorry for such a noob question... My first time around!

Code in the activity_my.xml file:

```
<ListView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ItemList"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView" />
```

What I need to do is associate it with an adapter. But this won't work:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new 
ArrayAdapter<String>(
 this,
 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     
 myStringArray);
```

My issue, namely, is that android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 is NOT the way to reference my ListView object in the MyActivity.XML file in Android Studio. I keep getting a "cannot resolve symbol 'r'" error.

Could anyone please clue me in?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think you'll have to give us more context. At least post some code. What does the layout XML look like? What error message(s) are you getting. Also, I know of a `ListItem` object and a `ListBox` control in VB6. What's an `ItemList`? What's it supposed to do?

Comment: You'll need to get access to the ListView using findViewById(), and then call setAdapter() on the ListView reference to set the Adapter.  The layout you feed to the Adapter just defines one row in the list...

Comment: What about the "cannot resolve symbol 'R'" error?

Answer (score 1):

First, the way to get hold of the ListView itself is relatively easy.  In an Activity subclass, you would do this:

```
ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ItemList);
```

In your example above, the ArrayAdapter needs a layout id in it's constructor.  This layout should contain a single TextView element (or some subclass) which will be used to render the list item.

```
<TextView .... />
```

In many cases, the value

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

is sufficient.  If you want different formatting, but still a single TextView, you can supply your own layout file in this constructor.

If you want anything more complex than a straight TextView, then you can create a subclass of ArrayAdapter, and override the getView method.  In this case, i'd recommend following the ViewHolder pattern as described here

[How can I make my ArrayAdapter follow the ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern)

The reasoning for the ViewHolder pattern can be seen here

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Finally, set the adapter on the ListView when you're all done:

```
itemList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

As for what "R" is, it's a file generated by your IDE (eclipse, intellij, android studio), that lives in the main package (as indicated in your AndroidManifest.xml).  Everytime you create a new element in a layout file with a new id, an entry gets added to that class under the "R.id" scope.  The same happens as you create layout files, drawables, dimension values, string values, etc...

If you're outside you're main package, just use the IDE to help you import the class.  Just take care you import the one from your package, as android it self has an "android.R" for it's own resources.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use the findViewById() method which is inherited from the AppCompatActivity class. Then call the list views setAdapter method.

```
  ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.'the id-name of your list view');
  listView.setAdapater(myAdapter);
```

The ArrayAdapter takes 3 parameters in to it's constructor. The first is context which you have provided 'this', this works because activities are subclasses of the Context class.

The second parameter you supplied; *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1.*
all this does is format your ListView, e.g. you could have checkboxes next to your list items if you liked by using android,  *android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked*.

The third is the array, the values at each index of your array will be used in the list view.

Answer (score 0):

Writing apps for Android is much more complicated than writing apps for Windows in vb6. You should really study basics and do some tutorials. Start [here!](http://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

But for your question, to get access to xml control in your code, first you have to make object of that control, e.g.

```
private Button button1;
```

then connect it with actual control from XML layout by method [findViewById()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int))

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id_in_xml_layout);
```

Comment: I get that, but what about the "cannot resolve symbol 'R'" error? -- THAT'S my big problem right now. Thanks!

Comment: R would be a generated class in your main package.  It contains an integer id for pretty much everything you can reference in your code.  This includes, but not limited to:

layout files,
element ids in layout files,
strings,
dimensions,
drawables,
etc...   Typically, either eclipse or android studio / intellij will handle generating this file for you on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntactical similarities with VB6, In Android what happens is UI elements are created as object hierarchy in the memory. To get a particular object, we use findViewById method with id of that particular element as argument.

You can get the List View.

```
ListView itemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ItemList);
```

Then,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                                        this,
                                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,     
                                        myStringArray);
```

Here,

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

is not referencing your `ItemList`.  This is for the Adapter. In the ListView you need to have a list of elements.

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 represent the template that is used to populate the list view.
```

then you do the,

```
itemList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

R issue many happens due to build failure, R is generated during the building of the project. To see the issue with the R, Can you add more code of your Activity class with the imports?