# Android custom arrayadapter & listview strange behavior

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have odd behavior on only the first item of the listview that appears on the screen; it is stuck to the second one. It is a dynamic listview that users can write text in and add/delete new lines. Please see the code below:

Button code to add a new line:

```
add_task.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            job_task_array.add(new JobTask_Model("", 50));
            job_task_update(rootView, item_job_task_height);
            for (int i = 0; i < job_task_array.size(); i++)
                Log.e("job_task", job_task_array.get(i).getJob_task_name());
        }
    });
```

This part animates it after clicking the button above:

```
    // This is called whenever we click 'add task' or 'delete task', does the whole animation cycle
public void job_task_update(final View view, final int job_task_heightmove) {
    add_task.setEnabled(false);
    Animation animation = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            job_task_listView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, (int) (job_task_height + (job_task_heightmove * interpolatedTime))));
        }
    };
    animation.setDuration(CreatePostingActivity.animationTime);
    view.startAnimation(animation); // Update job_task_height's value AFTER the shit animates because apparently it takes the current job_task_height
    view.postOnAnimationDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            job_task_height += job_task_heightmove;
            add_task.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }, CreatePostingActivity.animationTime * 2);
}
```

Custom adapter:

```
    // Object model for the posting_2 job_task_listView
public class JobTask_Model {
    private int job_task_seekbar_value;
    private String job_task_name;

    public JobTask_Model(String job_task_name, int job_task_seekbar_value) {
        this.job_task_seekbar_value = job_task_seekbar_value;
        this.job_task_name = job_task_name;
    }

    public String getJob_task_name() {
        return job_task_name;
    }

    public int getJob_task_seekbar_value() {
        return job_task_seekbar_value;
    }
}

/**
 * This class is the adapter for the tasks
 **/
public class JobTasks_Adapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final ArrayList<JobTask_Model> job_task_array;
    private Context context;

    public JobTasks_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList arrayList) {
        super(context, R.layout.item_job_task, arrayList);
        this.context = context;
        job_task_array = arrayList;
    }

    // Create static class for our special viewholder model, references item_job_task layout
    class JobTask_ViewHolder {
        EditText job_task_name;
        SeekBar job_task_seekbar;
        Button job_task_delete;
    }

    // This gets the view
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_job_task, parent, false);
            // configure view holder
            JobTask_ViewHolder viewHolder = new JobTask_ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.job_task_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_name);
            viewHolder.job_task_seekbar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_seekbar);
            viewHolder.job_task_delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_delete);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        JobTask_ViewHolder viewHolder = (JobTask_ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        // Set the bar value so it doesn't reset when we add another one in
        viewHolder.job_task_seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                job_task_array.get(position).job_task_seekbar_value = progress;
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }
        });

        viewHolder.job_task_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                job_task_array.get(position).job_task_name = s.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

        // Button to delete each task
        viewHolder.job_task_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                job_task_array.remove(position);
                job_task_update(rootView, -item_job_task_height);
            }
        });

        viewHolder.job_task_seekbar.setProgress(job_task_array.get(position).getJob_task_seekbar_value());
        viewHolder.job_task_name.setText(job_task_array.get(position).getJob_task_name());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'stuck to' ? do you mean visually?(if so please post image) or is the 1st array element 'showing' as the 2nd? (or something like that)

Comment: It's literally... changing when i click the add button. Both visually and in the array. I'm trying to debug it right now but running into problems

Comment: What happens on non-edge cases (aka... When you have 3 or more items  in the array already and you add a new one?)

Comment: All the other ones perform correctly. It is just the first item in the list that messes up. I have two separate lists doing separate things (so I use two adapters), and it seems like the first one that loads up an extra 'list item' will run into this issue. Everything else is working correctly.

Comment: the two adapters are the using the same arraylist as the input?

Comment: No, they both have their own arraylists, etc.

Comment: I've found out something -- the seekbar saves! But the edittext does not. Literally EVERYTHING ELSE works except for FIRST edittext view which = SECOND edittext view no matter what. This is a really annoying bug. I'm thinking of doing a hack that just populates empty fields to get rid of this bug.

Comment: If you can post this to github, I'd love to take a look at all of it (or at least a subset of your project which has 'this' part in it.)

Comment: https://github.com/lawonga/Temp/blob/master/c_DetailsInfo_fragment.java

Here you go, please be aware it is a bit messy - it's really supposed to be 3 classes... but I bunched them together to make it easier to work on (for me). Thanks a lot! I'm hoping its some bug where I missed a line or something... :(. Find the TODO's, that's where i put where the class is supposed to be split later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99037/discussion-between-mawalker-and-lawonga).

Answer (score 0):

Add some logcat statements into this method,

This should help you see if the 'tag' is being associated (created/read) properly, because the same 2 views should have a different 'tag' objects.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_job_task, parent, false);
        // configure view holder
        JobTask_ViewHolder viewHolder = new JobTask_ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.job_task_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_name);
        viewHolder.job_task_seekbar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_seekbar);
        viewHolder.job_task_delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_delete);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        Log.d("JobTasks_Adapter", "View was null" + view + " tag: " + viewHolder);
    } else {
        // this will give us address of the view
        Log.d("JobTasks_Adapter", "View was non-null" + view);
    }
    JobTask_ViewHolder viewHolder = (JobTask_ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    Log.d("JobTasks_Adapter", "viewHolder address " + viewHolder);

    ....
}
```

Comment: Output was extremely broken due to the animations... but I can see that the tags were different. I think something to do with the animation that's resetting it, but I can't really pinpoint what...

Answer (score 0):

```
When position == 0, view == null.

 @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
             JobTask_ViewHolder viewHolder 
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
                view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_job_task, parent, false);
                // configure view holder
                viewHolder = new JobTask_ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.job_task_name = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_name);
                viewHolder.job_task_seekbar = (SeekBar) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_seekbar);
                viewHolder.job_task_delete = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.job_task_delete);
                view.setTag(viewHolder);
            }else{
              viewHolder = (JobTask_ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your `static` isn't **static**

Make THIS:

```
// Create static class for our special viewholder model, references item_job_task layout
class JobTask_ViewHolder {
    EditText job_task_name;
    SeekBar job_task_seekbar;
    Button job_task_delete;
}
```

INTO THIS:

```
// Create static class for our special viewholder model, references item_job_task layout
static class JobTask_ViewHolder {
    EditText job_task_name;
    SeekBar job_task_seekbar;
    Button job_task_delete;
}
```

[How can I make my ArrayAdapter follow the ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern) as an example

Comment: Setting it to static didn't do anything :(