# Retrieving data from parse.com and displaying it in a multi-column listview for android

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I have done this android app that can READ data from parse.com and also can WRITE to it. 
Now I can get it to display in textview and but now I have a problem.

I need to display the data in a multi-column ListView and also add and display data from the tableLayout.

I have not tried anything yet as I don't know how to go about this.

How can I make it display in a multi-column ListView and also add and display data in a tableLayout?

Any examples would be highly appreciated

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/ .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern  try using ViewHolder with custom ArrayAdapter as per the link