# Android - ListFragment SimpleAdapter change color

Tags: android, colors, android-listfragment, simpleadapter

is there an easy way to change the colour of every second row

I tried this but unfortunately  it is not working.

```
  new SimpleAdapter(Activity.this,
                                    listElements,
                                    R.layout.list,
                                    new String[]{"dt", CONTENT, TIMESTAMP},
                                    new int[]{R.drawable.dt, R.id.content, R.id.timestamp}){
                                public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
                                    if (position%2 == 0) {
                                        v.setBackgroundColor(920000);
                                    } else {
                                    }
                                    return v;
                                }
                            }
                    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question is very close to correct; you have the right idea with overriding `getView()`, but you should change it to look like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    v = super.getView(position, v, parent);
    if (position%2 == 0) {
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xff920000);
    } else {
        v.setBackgroundColor(/* default color */);
    }
    return v;
}
```

The changes I've made are:

- Include a `super.getView()` call to get the default behavior for further modification
- Start your color value int literal with `0x` so that it's interpreted as a hexadecimal number
- Include the `ff` value for the alpha channel
- Also set the color in the `else` case to avoid problems with view recycling

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a custom adapter that implements getView like this answer does.

[How can I make my ArrayAdapter follow the ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832254/how-can-i-make-my-arrayadapter-follow-the-viewholder-pattern)

You can implement this code.

```
if(position % 2 == 0){ //even number
    //make a specific color
}
else if(position % 2 == 1){ //odd number
    //make a specific color
}
```

Comment: This is what I don't want to do? Isn't there another way?

Comment: Nope. You have to create a custom adapter no matter what.